# Automatically power-on Android phone at a given time?

Tags: automation, power-on

Is it possible to automatically power on Android phone at a given time?

Answer (score 1):

Technically, if your device is connected to a charger, it may be possible if your phone is rooted.

You can edit the program which shows the charging animation when your phone is powered off (typically stored in `playlpm` or `lpm` in `/system/bin`).

You could replace it with a simple shell script to reboot the phone when the time is equal to some value, assuming the system booted at that point has the `date` command available.

Obviously, this isn't an end-user solution. It's only for people who know at least a little programming and know what they are doing.

Source: https://arduandro.wordpress.com/2014/07/03/autobootstart-android-when-charger-is-connected/

Here is something to get you started. This should reboot your phone once it's 4pm (untested):

```
#!/system/bin/sh
while:
do
hr=`date +%H`
if test $hr -ge 16
    then
    /system/bin/reboot
else
    sleep 60
fi
done
```